# How to use mongoid-paperclip to upload multiple images through nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, file-upload, mongoid, paperclip

I have a rails app where I am trying to upload multiple images using nested_attributes but am running into great difficulty. The images don't seem to be saving to mongodb. I have followed this tutorial (though it seems lacking in detail): http://initializd.com/blog/2013/3/upload-multiple-files-with-html5-rails-mongoid-paperclip-and-google-cloud-storage

Basically, I have a form where a user is able to submit multiple listings (as nested attributes), and under each listing they are able to submit multiple images (also as nested attributes).

**Here is my form:**

The important part is the file_field_tag where the user is supposed to upload multiple images.

```
<%= nested_form_for @user, url: wizard_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

                <h1 style="margin-bottom: 6%;"> Add Listings </h1>

                <!-- nested fields -->
                <%= f.fields_for :listings do |builder| %>

                    <div class="field form-group">
                        <%= builder.label :type %> <br />
                        <%= builder.select :type, options_for_select(listing_types), {}, { :class => 'form-control', :required => 'true' } %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field form-group">
                        <%= builder.label :title %> <br />
                        <%= builder.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', required: 'true' %> <br />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field form-group">
                        <%= builder.label :description %> <br />
                        <%= builder.text_area :description, class: 'form-control', required: 'true' %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field form-group">
                        <%= builder.label :url %> <br />
                        <%= builder.text_field :url, class: 'form-control', required: 'true' %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field form-group">
                        <%= builder.label :zipcode %> <br />
                        <%= builder.text_field :zipcode, class: 'form-control', size: '24x4', required: 'true' %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field form-group">
                        <%= label_tag "upload images" %> <br />
                        <%= file_field_tag('listing_images_attributes_file', multiple: true, name: "user[listings_attributes][images_attributes][][image]", :required => 'true') %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field form-group">
                        <%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove this listing", :onclick =>"myFunction(this)" %>
                        <hr style="height: 2px; background-color: lightgray;">
                    </div>
                <% end %>


                <p style="margin-bottom: 15px;"><%= f.link_to_add "Add a listing", :listings %></p>


                <div class="actions">
                    <%= f.submit "Continue", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

**Here are my models:**

Listing Model:

```
class Listing
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String
  field :type, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :url, type: String
  field :zipcode, type: String

  # association between listing and user
  embedded_in :user

  # each listing has many images
  embeds_many :images, :cascade_callbacks => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Image Model:

```
class Image
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  field :listing_id, type: Integer # what is the purpose of this field exactly?

  embedded_in :listing
  has_mongoid_attached_file :image,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
    :url  => "/images/:id/:filename"
end
```

Snippet from user controller update action (basically my create):

```
def update
    @user = current_user
    #have to include steps to validate zip code
    case step
    when :personal
      @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    when :listings
      # should I build a listing as a default input?
      # listing = @user.listings.build
      @user.update_attributes(user_params)

    end

    render_wizard @user
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :zipcode, :bio, listings_attributes: [:title, :type, :description, :url, :zipcode, 
      { images_attributes: [:image] }, :_destroy, :id])
  end
```

Basically I am trying to get a user to be able to upload multiple listings, then multiple images under each listing. I wonder if this is possible using nested_attributes or will I have to handle the params manually? Also wondering whether my strong params are setup correctly. Here is a snippet from my server logs to show what my params look like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HUpgUfukx3Rqb2Ye3su1/9ts4byC1BFrB3HOLXgQeJr8Vrcf9JyQYvR52FC5psLPZGD2x2DlzmlQRRgEXQWo2g==", "user"=>{"listings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"type"=>"Airbnb", "title"=>"test", "description"=>"test", "url"=>"test", "zipcode"=>"test", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"57a2b9ba9cd25d2d94110543"}}}, "listing"=>{"images_attributes"=>[{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001016c2b20 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/vp/4hffkvd52gd317mgfqczqspm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160804-11668-1fjlflq.jpg>, @original_filename="event1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"listing[images_attributes][][image]\"; filename=\"event1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}]}, "commit"=>"Continue", "id"=>"listings"}
```

Sorry for the long description, but I was really hoping someone could answer this question. Thank you so much!